# Mobile data/Wifi schedular

Tags: mobile-data

I am using android version 4.3.. Usage of mobile data or Wifi consuming more battery power I need to turn them on/off for every 30 mins. So is there any options or apps available to schedule them??

Comment: The key is [automation](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/automation/info) (click it). There are automation apps *viz.* [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm), [AutomateIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage) and many others, that can do the job (though you should [edit] and detail more about for how long you want to have the data/wifi off) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the comment posted above, DS Battery Saver (available in the Play Store) has the functionality to turn off both data types and automatically turn them on to refresh data at specified intervals.

Comment: Could you mention the link here? I know its Pro version does the job.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.batrsaverpro